# What's the word for someone with two identities?

Tags: vocabulary

What's the word for someone with two identities? i.e. someone who acts in a certain way during some times (due to the culture and people around them) and acts differently (like with another identity) at another time?

The word may begin with c?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please be a little bit more specific as to what exactly you're looking for? Off the top of my head, I can think of at least two words that describe a person who changes their behavior depending on who they're with: **two-faced** and **hypocrite**.

Comment: "It may begin with _c_"....is this a crossword question?

Comment: As far as someone could remember, one of the words that describes the above situation begins with c...

Comment: Does the concept of "code switching" apply here?

Comment: Is this negative, or perhaps positive/neutarl?  When I lecture my calculus class, I act a certain way, but when I talk to my parents, I act a different way...

Answer (score 2):

One word starting with **c** is **chameleon**. A definition from the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/chameleon) is

> 1.2 A person who changes their opinions or behaviour according to the situation.

Answer (score 0):

I gather you're looking for a word or phrase to describe someone who consciously tries to please diffent groups by expressing different opinions about the same subject or by changing their behavior accordingly.  I would call them "double-faced" or "two-faced".

> from [**MW**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/double-faced) - false, hypocritical.

Comment: Thank you. Not quite looking for "two-faced" or "double-faced", these words seem to have an unpleasant notion to them. Looking more for someone that consciously adapts their behaviour to be able to serve two different situations/behaviours at different times. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think, a person with two identities can be called **JANUS-FACED.**

***Janus-faced***

ADJECTIVE

Having two sharply contrasting aspects or characteristics.

For example:

‘These reveal a Janus-faced director, working firmly in a tradition of Victorian hagiography, but clearly searching for contemporary relevance.’

(https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/janus-faced)

Answer (score 0):

I would say 'doublefaceted', 
but in different dictionaries there is only ***MULTIFACETED***.

I think, it's appropriate as there is no negative connotation.

For example, according to Macmillan Dictionary
https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/multifaceted:

***multifaceted***

ADJECTIVE 
FORMAL

containing many 
different aspects, 
features, or qualities